# In ruby on rails how to change table format

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

hi I am new to rails pls need help.

Table data from index.html.erb

```
<table class="table">                         
 <thead>  
  <tr> 
    <th>Area</th> 
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <%@a1s.each do |ada| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=ada.Area%></td>
      <td><%=ada.Item%></td>
      <td><%=ada.Year%></td>
      <td><%=ada.Value%></td>
    </tr>
  <%end%> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

[index.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyIWs.jpg)

how to change index.html.erb table to example converted table

1. convert year data as a header and show their value.
2. Item and Area names show ones and next country shown in next row.

[example converted table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkDMh.jpg)

Comment: Is this your school assignment? Can you please show what you have tried, and what the error is. It feels a little like you're posting your school work, asking someone to complete it for you.

Comment: No, it is not my school work in my school I use python, I am learning myself ruby on rails. hi, @gwalshington image(1) index.html.erb I complete that much I unable to convert table to example converted table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> convert year data as a header and show their value.

You are looking for a **list of all years in the data**. You could do that, for example, with:

```
@a1s.map(&:Year).uniq
```

> Item and Area names show ones and next country shown in next row.

I'd advise using `.group_by` to organise the data for each row in the table.

```
<%@a1s.group_by(&:Area).each do |area, adas_in_area| %>
  <%adas_in_area.group_by(&:Item).each do |item, adas_in_area_for_item| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=area%></td>
      <td><%=item%></td>
      # TODO -- You need to find the value for each year here :)
    </tr>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: As a side note, I'd advise against using cryptic variable names like `@a1s` and `adas`. I have absolutely no idea what either of those variables mean ;)

Comment: hi, @Tom Load thanks for your help but I was unable to find the # TODO -- You need to find the value for each year here :).

Comment: @adarsh I was hoping to give you a strong push in the right direction, rather than necessarily giving an entire solution that you can copy ad verbum. In part this is because I feel there's value in you figuring out part of the solution yourself, but also, I don't feel entirely comfortable giving a "complete" solution with only partial information -- You never showed what `@a1s` actually is, so it's hard for me to know what edge cases may need to be accounted for.

Comment: That line of code *could* be something like: `covered_years.each { |year| ada = adas_in_area_for_item.find {|ada| ada.Year == year}; ... }`, but then you'll also need to figure out how to define `covered_years` 

Comment: (Hint: `covered_years` will also be a very useful variable for defining the header!)